# A matrix of a single 1 in each row and 0 elsewhere

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, notation, terminology, computational-mathematics

Is there a particular name given to a matrix of ***m*** rows and ***n*** columns such that it must have one and only one 1 in each row and 0 elsewhere? For instance:

```
0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 1 0 0
0 1 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0 1
0 0 1 0 0 0 0
```

Note: It may or may not be a square matrix.

Comment: Reduced Row Echelon Form looks similar to this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_echelon_form#Reduced_row_echelon_form

Comment: Well you can call it sparse, which refers to a matrix of mostly zeros, of course this is independent of what the other entries are and is more of a description of how many zeros there are

Comment: For a square matrix of that form it'd be a permutation matrix, but I'm not sure what it'd be called otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't heard of a name for the class of such matrices. If I had to suggest a name for such a matrix, I would call it a "row selection matrix", since if $A \in R^{m\times n}$ is such a matrix and $B \in R^{n\times k}$ an arbitrary matrix, then every row of $AB$ is also a row of $B$.

Answer (score 1):

Permutation Matrix
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Permutation_matrix

It applies to squared matrices, but you can generalize for nonsquare matrices

Comment: Yes, but this is only a permutation matrix if it also has only one 1 per column, which the OP hasn't specified.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a common name for this type of matrix.  However, a nice way to describe it is that the rows of your matrix are rows of the identity matrix with possible repetition.